# How to reference a variable when multiple cases are combined?

Tags: scala

Is there a way to give a reference name to a variable when multiple cases are combined using `match` in `Scala`?

Code:

Assume `Gender` enum has three possible values like `male`, `female` and `other`.

```
(nameOption, genderOption) match {
    case (Some(name), Some(Gender.Male)) | (Some(name), Some(Gender.FeMale))=> s"$name gender is either male or female"
    case (None, Some(Gender.Male)) | (None, Some(Gender.FeMale)) => //some print statement
    case (Some(name), Some(Gender.Other)) =>  //some print statement
    case _ => //some print statement
}
```

First case `case (Some(name), Some(Gender.Male)) | (Some(name), Some(Gender.FeMale))` is complier error as *`name` is already defined in scope*.

If I don't combine cases in my actual code cyclomatic complexity increases.

Comment: If you put `(Some(name), Some(Gender.Other))` first then you can just use `(Some(name),_)`. As a general rule, put the most specific cases first so that you can use catch-all matches later.

Comment: Scala would not allowed that syntax because the `name` replicated.But instead use the formula on how to get the tuple value.

Comment: Something like this. `case v: (a@Option[String], Some(Gender.Male)) | (b@Option[String], Some(Gender.FeMale))` or `case v@(a@Option[String], Some(Gender.Male)) | (b@Option[String], Some(Gender.FeMale))` ..

Comment: And (depending on your logic), you may be able to `.getOrElse` the optionality away before matching.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can replace your first case to:

```
case (Some(name), Some(Gender.Male) |  Some(Gender.FeMale))=> s"$name gender is either male or female"
```

Update - even better - Thanks to @Astrid

```
case (Some(name), Some(Gender.Male | Gender.FeMale)) => s"$name gender is either male or female"
```

Comment: or even to `case (Some(name), Some(Gender.Male | Gender.FeMale))`

Answer (score 7):

you can try the following

```
(nameOption, genderOption) match {
    case (Some(name), Some(gender) if (gender == Gender.Male || gender == Gender.Female) => s"$name gender is either male or female"

}
```

Comment: yeah it really depends on the case. My purpose was just to demonstrate how the same thing can be achieved by giving using the name variable. of course there is room for improvement

Answer (score 6):

In addition to the answers already given, if you find yourself repeating the `Gender.Male | Gender.FeMale` match clause a lot in different parts of your code you might want to consider a custom extractor.

```
object BinaryGender {
  def unapply(gender: Gender.Gender) : Option[Gender.Gender] = {
    Some(gender).filter(_ != Gender.Other)
  }
}

(nameOption, genderOption) match {
  case (Some(name), Some(BinaryGender(_))) => s"$name gender is either male or female"
  case (None, Some(BinaryGender(_))) => //some print statement
  ...
}
```