# case class - combine pattern match

Tags: scala, pattern-matching

I have a method defined as below and wanted to combine pattern match. The or operator give me compiler error (||).

```
def isPaired(input: String): Boolean = {

    def go(x: List[Char], level: Int = 0): Boolean = {
      x match {
        case Nil => true
        case '(' :: xs1 if level < 0 => false
        case '[' :: xs1 if level < 0 => false
        case '{' :: xs1 if level < 0 => false
        case ')' :: xs1 if level == 0 => false
        case ']' :: xs1 if level == 0 => false
        case '}' :: xs1 if level == 0 => false
        case '(' :: xs1 => go(xs1, level + 1)
        case '[' :: xs1 => go(xs1, level + 1)
        case '{' :: xs1 => go(xs1, level + 1)
        case ')' :: xs1 => go(xs1, level - 1)
        case ']' :: xs1 => go(xs1, level - 1)
        case '}' :: xs1 => go(xs1, level - 1)
        case _ :: xs1 => go(xs1, level + 1)
      }

    }
    go(input.toList)
  }
```

The below gives compiler error:

```
case '(' :: xs1 || '[' :: xs1 || '{' :: xs1  if level < 0 => false
case ('(' :: xs1) || ('[' :: xs1) || ('{' :: xs1)  if level < 0 => false
```

How to apply or condition?

Comment: Close, the correct syntax would be `case ('(' | '[' | '{') :: xs1 if (level < 0) => false`.

Answer (score 2):

There are several issue with what you tried:

1. You are using the `||` (`Or` operator) instead of the `|` (`Pipe` operator) to represent multiple case, as @Luis commented - see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6484137/how-does-pipe-in-pattern-matching-work)
2. You are to try to reference a variable when multiple case are combined - see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56749207/5826349)

So what you can try indeed is:

```scala
def isPaired(input: String): Boolean = {

    def go(x: List[Char], level: Int = 0): Boolean = {
      x match {
        case Nil => true
        case ('(' | '[' | '{') :: xs1 if level < 0 => false
        case ')' :: xs1 if level == 0 => false
        case ']' :: xs1 if level == 0 => false
        case '}' :: xs1 if level == 0 => false
        case '(' :: xs1 => go(xs1, level + 1)
        case '[' :: xs1 => go(xs1, level + 1)
        case '{' :: xs1 => go(xs1, level + 1)
        case ')' :: xs1 => go(xs1, level - 1)
        case ']' :: xs1 => go(xs1, level - 1)
        case '}' :: xs1 => go(xs1, level - 1)
        case _ :: xs1 => go(xs1, level + 1)
      }

    }
    go(input.toList)
  }
```

Or even more condensed:

```scala
def isPaired(input: String): Boolean = {

    def go(x: List[Char], level: Int = 0): Boolean = {
      x match {
        case Nil => true
        case ('(' | '[' | '{') :: xs1 if level < 0 => false
        case (')' | ']' | '}') :: xs1 if level == 0 => false
        case ('(' | '[' | '{') :: xs1 => go(xs1, level + 1)
        case (')' | ']' | '}') :: xs1 => go(xs1, level - 1)
        case _ :: xs1 => go(xs1, level + 1)
      }

    }
    go(input.toList)
  }
```